# Does Pretty Fly count towards Lord of the Flies transformation?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I know Halo of Flies counts, but does Pretty Fly (pill or slot machine) count towards the transformation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the pretty fly through pill or slot machine does not count towards the transformation.

In some runs, I've got more than 3 pretty fly pills, but 1) I did not transform and 2) I still had to get 3 items required to transform.

Only the items listed [here](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Lord_of_the_flies#Lord_Of_The_Flies) will transform you into lord of the flies.